# deleted partition in windows and created new partition but want to recover data back? urgent

Tags: data-recovery

by mistake i have deleted wrong partition. and now created partition from that unallocated space.

Is there any way to get all data back?

I have tried to recover data by stellar phoenix but unable to recover.

Any one can help me?

Comment: did you write any data on that new partition?

Comment: Stellar phoenix is windows software. What are you trying to recover? A windows partition?

Comment: @Takkat 
N0 i haven't write any data to it.

Comment: Yeah @Rinzwind i'm trying to recover windows partition.

Comment: From Ubuntu (everything else is off topic here) you may be able to recover your partitions or data on these with Testdisk which can be installed and run from an [Ubuntu CD as shown here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu).

Comment: @user216454 you should use windows tools to do this and not Ubuntu. We support Windows to an extend but not 100% so you are better of asking this on a Windows support forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EaseUs free partition manage software to backup and recovery your disk. It can be to partition your disk, cloning, copy, merge and recovery your disk. It can improve your disk space. You also don't have to manually to disk partition. Just need according to the software instructions to use .